# mi android studio no termina de instalar

Tags: android-studio

[image: mi android studio no termina de instalar]

descargue la versión 4.0 porque mi pc es algo antigua y cuando la instalación llega a ese nivel no haces mas nada se queda de esa forma.

Comment: XD, se como se siente. Android studio es muyyy pesado, y mas sus dependencia. Realmente se queda la pagina paralizada o es que la ventana despegable es mas grande que la pantalla?

Comment: Intenta cerrar la ventana despegable y dime que te dice

Comment: Nada, sigue igual.

Comment: Que raro, parece que la instalación del los componentes no tuvo errores.

Comment: ¿Al compilar la app y obtener he ejecutar en tu telefono no te sale algun error?, ¿Cual te sale?